# Using Structural Type in Scala occurs NoSuchMethodException

Tags: scala, lambda, nosuchmethoderror, structural-typing

I am writing a function with three parameters `f`, `from`, `to`. `f` should be any object with `apply` method that consumes and yields an Int.

```
 def printValues(f: {def apply(n: Int):Int}, from: Int, to: Int) {
   for(i <- from to `to`) print(f(i) + " ")
   print("\n")
 }
```

I use structural type here to guarantee `f` has `apply()` method.

As I invoke the method `printValues()` with an `Array[Int]`, everything goes well.

```
printValues(Array(1,1,2,3,5,8,13,21,34,55), 3, 6)
```

And I try to invoke the method with a lambda expression, the mess comes

```
printValues((x: Int) => x * x, 3, 6)
```

error information

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: ch18.p8.Main$$$Lambda$97/474675244.apply(int)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1786)
    at ch18.p8.Main$.reflMethod$Method3(Ch18.scala:270)
    at ch18.p8.Main$.$anonfun$printValues$1(Ch18.scala:270)
    at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction1$mcII$sp.apply(JFunction1$mcII$sp.java:12)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike.$anonfun$map$1(TraversableLike.scala:234)
    at scala.collection.immutable.Range.foreach(Range.scala:156)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike.map(TraversableLike.scala:234)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike.map$(TraversableLike.scala:227)
    at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.map(Traversable.scala:104)
    at ch18.p8.Main$.printValues(Ch18.scala:270)
    at ch18.p8.Main$.delayedEndpoint$ch18$p8$Main$1(Ch18.scala:274)
    at ch18.p8.Main$delayedInit$body.apply(Ch18.scala:267)
    at scala.Function0.apply$mcV$sp(Function0.scala:34)
    at scala.Function0.apply$mcV$sp$(Function0.scala:34)
    at scala.runtime.AbstractFunction0.apply$mcV$sp(AbstractFunction0.scala:12)
    at scala.App.$anonfun$main$1$adapted(App.scala:76)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:389)
    at scala.App.main(App.scala:76)
    at scala.App.main$(App.scala:74)
    at ch18.p8.Main$.main(Ch18.scala:267)
    at ch18.p8.Main.main(Ch18.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at scala.reflect.internal.util.ScalaClassLoader.$anonfun$run$2(ScalaClassLoader.scala:98)
    at scala.reflect.internal.util.ScalaClassLoader.asContext(ScalaClassLoader.scala:32)
    at scala.reflect.internal.util.ScalaClassLoader.asContext$(ScalaClassLoader.scala:30)
    at scala.reflect.internal.util.ScalaClassLoader$URLClassLoader.asContext(ScalaClassLoader.scala:129)
    at scala.reflect.internal.util.ScalaClassLoader.run(ScalaClassLoader.scala:98)
    at scala.reflect.internal.util.ScalaClassLoader.run$(ScalaClassLoader.scala:90)
    at scala.reflect.internal.util.ScalaClassLoader$URLClassLoader.run(ScalaClassLoader.scala:129)
    at scala.tools.nsc.CommonRunner.run(ObjectRunner.scala:22)
    at scala.tools.nsc.CommonRunner.run$(ObjectRunner.scala:21)
    at scala.tools.nsc.ObjectRunner$.run(ObjectRunner.scala:39)
    at scala.tools.nsc.CommonRunner.runAndCatch(ObjectRunner.scala:29)
    at scala.tools.nsc.CommonRunner.runAndCatch$(ObjectRunner.scala:28)
    at scala.tools.nsc.ObjectRunner$.runAndCatch(ObjectRunner.scala:39)
    at scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner.runTarget$1(MainGenericRunner.scala:61)
    at scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner.run$1(MainGenericRunner.scala:88)
    at scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner.process(MainGenericRunner.scala:99)
    at scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner$.main(MainGenericRunner.scala:104)
    at scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner.main(MainGenericRunner.scala)
```

I try to verify object `lambdaxxx` has function `apply`(In Scala REPL)

```
scala> val f = (x: Int) => x * x
f: Int => Int = $$Lambda$1020/826690115@7f8633ae

scala> f.apply
   def apply(v1: Int): Int
```

I got two bug reports:

[Seemingly using structural type](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-10175)

[A more weird bug demo](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-9919)

So maybe I also fall into this trap.

By the way, If `printValues()` is below, the lambda expression can fit the method `printValues2()`.

```
def printValues2(f: (Int) => (Int), from: Int, to: Int) {
  for(i <- from to `to`) print(f(i) + " ")
  print("\n")
}
```

Thank you for sharing your idea, best wishes.

Comment: printValues((x: Int) => x * x, 3, 6) works for me in REPL and IDEA

Comment: @Ivan Which Scala version? OP should specify it as well.

Comment: @lvan I run the code in scala-2.9.1(jdk 1.7), life is good. However, the mess comes when I go back to scala-2.12.2(jdk 1.8).

Comment: Works on 2.11.11

Comment: The bug in Scala's issue tracker: https://github.com/scala/bug/issues/10334 and a pending fix https://github.com/scala/scala/pull/5977, probably going to be part of 2.12.3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just partial explanation of this bug and workaround.

Structural types are using reflection, so every time you call a method from structural type (like `f(i)` in your case) you're doing something like `f.getClass.getMethod.invoke(i)` (so method resolving happens in runtime). Let's simplify your code (2.12.2 REPL):

```
scala> val f: {def apply(n: Int):Int} = (x: Int) => x * x
f: AnyRef{def apply(n: Int): Int} = $$Lambda$1250/571435580@5eb041b5

scala> f(4)
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: $$Lambda$1250/571435580.apply(int)
  at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1786)
  at .reflMethod$Method1(<console>:13)
  ... 29 elided
```

And introspect it to see what methods `f` actually has in runtime

```
scala> f.getClass.getMethods
res21: Array[java.lang.reflect.Method] = Array(public int $$Lambda$1250/571435580.apply$mcII$sp(int), public final void java.lang.Object.wait(long,int) throws java.lang.InterruptedException, public final native void java.lang.Object.wait(long)

scala> f.getClass.getMethods()(0)
res23: java.lang.reflect.Method = public int $$Lambda$1250/571435580.apply$mcII$sp(int)
```

Here you can easily see that scala (roughly saying) compiled your `Int => Int` lambda into `apply$mcII$sp` method, however reflective call is looking for `apply(int)` method which wasn't added to final byte-code for some reason.

Here is the workaround:

```
scala> val m = f.getClass.getMethods()(0)
m: java.lang.reflect.Method = public int $$Lambda$1250/571435580.apply$mcII$sp(int)

scala> m.setAccessible(true)

scala> m.invoke(f, new Integer(5))
res50: Object = 25
```

You'll probably have to do this as a backup in case `f(i)` throws an exception.

However requiring `Int => Int` is much faster of course :)

Answer (score 0):

Seems it's a **Scala compiler** bug in **Scala 2.12 compiler** doesn't generate the **specify type** method:

```
  val t1  = (x: String) => x + x
  t1.getClass.getMethods.foreach(println)
```

> ...
>
> public java.lang.Object TestFooBar$$$Lambda$6/1265210847.apply(java.lang.Object)
>   public final void java.lang.Object.wait(long,int) throws java.lang.InterruptedException

In the above code, get all methods from **high order function** `f1`, and find it only has `Object ... apply(java.lang.Object)` method, doesn't have `String ... apply(java.lang.String)` method, so when pass it to the `structural type`: `f: {def apply(n: String):String}`, it will throw `NoSuchMethodException`.

```
  val t2 = new Function1[String, String] {
    def apply(x: String): String = x + x
  }
```

> ...
>
> public java.lang.String TestFooBar$$anon$1.apply(java.lang.String)
>   public java.lang.Object TestFooBar$$anon$1.apply(java.lang.Object)
>
> ...

In the above code, we use **anonymous class** `Function1` for this. essentially **high order function**: `(x: String) => x + x` is equal to `new Function1[String, String]`. but we can find the **anonymous class** has generated a **specify type** method: `String ... apply(java.lang.String)`.

so this maybe it's a **Scala 2.12 compiler issue**, not generate the **specify type** method for **high order function**.

and Why use **String** not **Int** for this test?

Since `Function1` has [@specialized](http://www.scala-notes.org/2011/04/specializing-for-primitive-types/) the **primitive type(Int)**, need to avoid this affect.